# How to place div inside an inline-block div?

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

But when I add a div inside to the red div, the green div is moved down

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div style="width:25vw; background-color:red;height:200px;display:inline-block">
         <div style="vertical-align: top">this is the first child div</div>
         <div style="vertical-align: top">this is the second child div</div>
    </div>
     <div style="width:25vw; background-color:green;height:200px;display:inline-block">
        inside div
    </div>
```

Comment: you can use table format with align left and right.

Comment: do you mean display:table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your green div. You don't need it for the red div.

This has to do with line boxes for the text inside the other divs which changes the baseline for the text. Honestly, I can't remember the details at the moment but it's a common thing.

The gap between the divs is created because your elements are inline, just like text, so a space "between words" is created for you. To get rid of the space, don't have any space between the divs. That is:

`<div>words</div><
div>more words</div>`

Or

`<div>words</div><div>
more words
</div>`

Notice there is no space between the closing div tag and the opening of the second one.

Comment: Thank you! That works! I did not know that trick for the line boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work.

```css
table td {
  text-align:center;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding:0 15px
}
table {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0100 50%, #008004 51%)
}
```

```html
<table class="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">div</td>
      <td>div</td>
      <td>div</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>div</td>
      <td>div</td>
      <td colspan="2">div</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

You can add `float: left` to the first div and it will align properly.

Comment: Okay, I did that and now first and second div (inside red div) are in the same row. I am looking for having 1st row 1 column, 2nd row 2 columns.

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: this should be a comment.